# text in table cells not centered as in headers

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
.one {
    width: 13%;
}

.two {
    width: 30%;
}

.three {
    width: 30%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class= "one">Quantity</th>
        <th class= "two">Info</th>
        <th class= "three">Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity1" value=""/>
        <td class = "two">Cheap Monday Jeans 30/34 </td>
        <td class = "three">$39.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity2" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">Herschel Bag (free) </td>
        <td class = "three">$129.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity3" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">Diesel t-shirt (s) </td>
        <td class = "three">$59.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity4" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">Superdry Patrol Lite Jacket (m) </td>
        <td class = "three">$129.99 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity5" value=""/></td>
        <td class = "two">I love Canada t-shirt (s) </td>
        <td class = "three">$19.99 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want the table rows (clothes information & prices) to be aligned right below the table headers. I don't know why table rows are skewed to the left and cannot be aligned right below to the headers.

[image]

Comment: Works for me (Firefox). http://jsfiddle.net/6hY2V/ What's your problem?

Comment: Post a link to imagur or another image hosting site.  That would make helping you easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "*alignment*"? Do you want [`th, td { text-align: right; }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)?

Comment: Hey guys, I uploaded the image. As you can see, the informations and the actual prices are to the left. I want these to be aligned right below the Info and Price. Hope this makes sense. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you forgot to close the td after the first input.

```
 <td class = "one"><input type="text" name="quantity1" value=""/></td>
```

You can add this css to make them center

```
td
{
    text-align:center;    
}
```

Have a look on this **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/6hY2V/1/)**

Comment: It still would be valid HTML :-)

Comment: you can try to change from td to table... 

table { text-align:center; }   . Is this live somewhere that i can have a look into?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your css:

```
td.two, td.three {
  text-align:right;
}
```

You need the `td` prefix cause your `th` is using the same css class.

I hope that helps.